# Variable doesn't change outside of function

Tags: jquery, forms, variables

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/veksen/7TRgE/1/

If I call the variable value from inside my function, it works. However, it doesn't if I call it outside of the function.

I feel like it has something to do with change, as it is first assigned ok, but won't change.

```
var diff_res = { norm:0, nm:-40, hell:-100 };
var difficulty = "hell"; 
$("select").change(function () {
    difficulty = $("select option:selected").val();
    $(".inside").text(diff_res[difficulty]);
})
.change();

var char_fr = 30;
char_fr += diff_res[difficulty];

$(".outside").text(diff_res[difficulty]);
```

​

Comment: Do you have a "selected" option?

Comment: yes I do, <option value="hell" selected>Hell</option> (html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

By re-executing, I meant something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var diff_res = {
            norm: 0,
            nm: -40,
            hell: -100
        },
        difficulty = "hell",
        char_fr = 30,
        changeOutside = function changeOutside() {
            $(".outside").text(diff_res[difficulty]);
        };
    $("select").change(function () {
        difficulty = $("select option:selected").val();
        $(".inside").text(diff_res[difficulty]);
        changeOutside();
    }).change();
    char_fr += diff_res[difficulty];
});
```

The point was that `$(".outside").text(diff_res[difficulty]);` is only being executed once, when the DOM is loaded, which is why the `text()` is initially set to `-100`. To change the `.outside` again, you need to re-run `$(".outside").text(diff_res[difficulty]);`

**ORIGINAL:**

Your problem is that:

```
$(".outside").text(diff_res[difficulty]);
```

is only executed one time, in the `$(document).ready()` function. If you want it to change more often, you'll need to re-execute that in your `change` handler.

Comment: Adding a handler around the "outside" code causes me trouble, as it includes a `var += value` inside of a `each` handler, causing the outside code to add up every time I change the dropdown

Comment: Thanks a lot so far! http://jsfiddle.net/veksen/7TRgE/4/

If you check the JSFiddle, you'll see that test1 and test2 update just fine, however with the variable alone (in test3), it doesn't.

My current project uses the variable by itself (with `(diff_res[difficulty])` added outside, prior to inserting. Which I could adapt just fine.... however, I'm puzzled on to why it happens?

Comment: The value of `.test3` doesn't change because the source variable (`char_fr`) never has its value changed from `30`. `.test3` will change when the value of `char_fr` has changed (although the `select.change()` event will have to fire to initiate the change in `.test3`). Change it to `$(".test3").text(char_fr+=300);` to update the value of the variable at the same time you display it.

Answer (score 1):

`.inside` have a event which says: "If someone change-me [...]". `.outisde` have not events. So:

```
$(".outside").text(diff_res[difficulty]);
```

Will execute once only.

See http://jsfiddle.net/7TRgE/2/

Selected option is: "nm" and default value is "-40".

Comment: Well, I can get the bit of code outside to update, but it doesn't behave well at all with my code that uses .each to find data in the html and adds it with a +=, only adding it around the outside selector  has no effect (probably from another outside variable?)

it works in the jsfiddle, but not on my full project